# store output of ls - lrt in two different variables

Tags: shell, scripting

I want to store out put of ls - lrt | tail -2 in two different variables and get the base file name. file name have the pattern YYYYMMDD_filename. I want to compare both the files with current date and pick the previous day file. please help. I m new to shell scripting.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Here's a code snippet that will get your started. `# files=$(ls -ltr  | tail -2  | awk '{print $9}')

# echo $files
20143818_file1 20143817_file2`

What do you mean by comparing both the files?

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question. To get all the files with yesterday's date:

```
yesterday=$( date -d yesterday +%Y%m%d )
files=( "$yesterday"_* )
```

It's generally advised to [avoid parsing the output of `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs).